# Fullscreen not working in Kindle using wine

Tags: 18.04, wine, window, fullscreen, kindle

I recently installed [Amazon Kindle](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10597) using Wine 3.0 and PlayOnLinux on my Ubuntu 18.04. Everything works perfectly except for the full screen mode. When I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd> I see a smaller windowed mode with everything else disappearing as shown below in the image.

[image: buggy full screen mode in Kindle]

I want the app to completely occupy my screen (hiding the dock and top bar)  when I click on full-screen mode. Is there a way this can be solved?

Comment: Many of us may not be familiar with this Windows app. Can you [edit] your question to include some details like where you get this app from and what you are expecting to happen that does not work right?

Comment: I installed the app using PlayOnLinux's Virtual Drive and inbuilt setup, what I am expecting to happen I've edited in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I have found a workaround:

Instead of going in full screen mode from a maximized window,

1. Unmaximize (yep, that's a word according to Ubuntu) the window first

[image: Window options]

2. Now press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd> or go to `View` -> `Full Screen` and you'll get the full screen window as shown below!

[image: Full Screen Mode]

Note: This is just a workaround and does not solve the problem actually. It is still not possible to go into full screen mode from a maximized window of the app. I hope the bug is resolved in future.